# Radius of curvature polar

Tags: calculus, geometry, polar-coordinates, plane-curves, curvature

$$ρ = a \sin^3({\theta/3}) ,
ρ=\sqrt{(x^2+y^2)}$$

Please help me find the radius of curvature of this problem I have solved parametric and polynomial forms but i am unable to get this

Comment: Hold on. What happened to your $a$ in the second equality of $\rho$?

Comment: I was trying to describe ρ in polar form

Answer (score 6):

In polar coordinates $\rho=\rho(\theta)$ the radius of curvature is given by [link](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RadiusofCurvature.html):
$$\large R=\frac{\left(\rho^2+\left(\frac{d\rho}{d\theta}\right)^2\right)^{3/2}}{\left|\rho^2+2\left(\frac{d\rho}{d\theta}\right)^2-\rho\left(\frac{d^2\rho}{d\theta^2}\right)\right|}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your innovative answer

Comment: @Adk do you know about accepting/upvoting/etc.?

Comment: No i am sorry i don't

Comment: I am sorry but i don't have enough reputation, i will upvote you when i do.